# chrome не дает сделать xss

Tags: xss

В инпут ввожу строку `"><script>alert(111);</script>`, а хром эскейпит первый quote. Подскажите, как обойти это? Попробовал так же в Microsoft Edge, тоже самое .

source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Tag FORM</title>
<script>
var f1 = function(val){
document.getElementById("q").setAttribute("value",val);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form> 
<input type="text" id="q" name="q" class="search-inp" value="4" >
<!-- <input name="q" class="search-inp" id="q" type="text" value=''>   <script>alert(111);</script>'> -->
        <input name="o1" type="button" value="1" onclick="f1(document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Обычно браузеры сами-по-себе не занимаются такими вещами. Поэтому уточню: в какой момент (и при каких условиях) происходит эскейпирование символа браузером?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev когда вставляю в инпут строку и нажимаю на кнопку. Далее в админ тулз edit as HTML и вижу, что символ эскейпирован

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что XSS работает именно так? Вся суть XSS сводится к выполнению кода при _отрисовке страницы барузером_. Иными словами, ваше значение, должно быть подставлено в атрибут `value` на стороне сервера. Если вы можете выполнять JavaScript код на странице, то либо вы уже провели XSS, либо проведение этой атаки не требуется.